# how to access the value of 'Id' in an anchor tag in the component to JS controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have an anchor tag in the component where i need to get the id of the anchor tag to my JavaScript controller.

### Component

```
<a class="notifLinkTwo" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="notificationDropdownId" aria-expanded="false" onclick="{!c.clickButtonTwo}">
```

### Controller

```
clickButtonTwo : function(component, event, helper){
    var x = document.getElementById("notificationDropdownId");
         alert('x: '+ x);
}
```

---

Currently I am not getting the value for the x in the alert.

Comment: id's are not supported, considering that these are changed on runtime, you will have to use aura:id's and component.find() to get the matching element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the DOM Access contaiment [Guidelines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) for aura components

**Component:**

```
<a class="notifLinkTwo" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aura:id="notificationDropdownId" aria-expanded="false" onclick="{!c.clickButtonTwo}">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
({ clickButtonTwo : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        // access the DOM in c:domLocker
        console.log("notification: ", cmp.find("notificationDropdownId").getElement());
    }
})
```